# Coturn stun server returned an error with code=701

Tags: ubuntu, server, webrtc, coturn

I have my own server with ubuntu 19.

NOTE: I need a stun/turn server for a video chat web application. It works already if both devices are in the same network.

I have successfully installed and configured coturn. I can successfully start the turnserver by running:
`turnserver` or `nohup turnserver &` in the terminal.

NOTE: I have an `SSH` connection to my server.

I also ensured that the necessary ports are open and checked them with `netstat -tulpn`.

I have been also restarting coturn a few times while testing `sudo service coturn restart`.

I use these configurations in the `turnserver.conf`:

```
# Also tried 80
listening-port=3478
# Also tried 443
tls-listening-port=5349
listening-ip=<MY-IP4>
listening-ip=<MY-IP6>
relay-ip=<MY-IP4>
external-ip=<MY-IP4>
oauth
user=root:<password>
userdb=/var/lib/turn/turndb
no-stdout-log
```

This is my iceServers config in js, which I believe should work (I have done TONS of other combinations).

```
var pcConfig = {
  'iceServers': [
    {
      'urls': 'stun:<MY-IP4>:80'
    },
    {
      'urls': 'turn:<MY-IP4>:80',
      'credential': '<PASSWORD>',
      'username': 'root'
    }
  ]
};
```

I have done TONS of different stun/turn server combinations, e.g.:

- I used google's stun servers: stun.l.google.com:19302, stun2.l.google.com:19302 etc.
- I tried ports 3478 and 5349 (of course after restarting coturn)
- I tried to use credentials for the stun server, but I am sure it does not need them
- I tried to use IP6 address

I have also been doing tests live on my webproject and also here:
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/

Basically the testing URL above always gives me:

```
Note: errors from onicecandidateerror above are not neccessarily fatal. For example an IPv6 DNS lookup may fail but relay candidates can still be gathered via IPv4.
The server stun:<MY-IP4>:80 returned an error with code=701:
STUN server address is incompatible.
The server stun:<MY-IP4>:80 returned an error with code=701:
STUN server address is incompatible.
```

It does not matter whether I use google's stun server or my own, the error is the same.

My webproject and the video chat WORKS great if I use the same network, but I believe stun and turn servers are not used in the same network.

Also while I updated my JS file I always deleted cache, so the new JS file was used. So that was also not an issue.

**EDIT**

This combination does not give an error, only:

```
Note: errors from onicecandidateerror above are not 
neccessarily fatal. For example an IPv6 DNS 
lookup may fail but relay candidates can still be gathered via IPv4.
```

Tested on https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/

```
{
  'urls': 'stun:<MY-IP6>:80'
},
{
  'urls': 'turn:<MY-IP4>:80',
  'credential': '<PASSWORD>',
  'username': 'root'
}
```

I simply used IP6 for the stun and IP4 for turn.
Video chat in different network still does not work, nowhere other errors to find.

**EDIT:**

Noticed today that https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/
does not work. I had no errors on firefox. BUT you can enter some nonesense there and it will also show no errors...

**EDIT:**

I have also added now valid certificates:

```
cert=/usr/local/etc/turn.pem                                                                                    
pkey=/usr/local/etc/turn.key.pem
```

Seems to work. I restarted coturn and status tells me that everything is running without issues.

Video chat still does not work in different networks.

Comment: Maybe interesting for others: Firefox (v 85.0) has not yet implemented onicecandidateerror but uses oniceconnectionstatechange with state 'failed' to report connectivity issues if TURN sever cannot be reached e.g server or port is blocked, TURN request not allowed, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. I was looking at the whole thing from the wrong angle. The TURN/STUN server setup is correct.

The issue is with the client/server code. The signaling does not work.

I followed [this](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/) article, but I have problems to setup the signaling service. I think this must be asked in a new question.